# How can I define a ⊕ operator?

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions, downvalues

What is wrong with the following code?

```
CirclePlus := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {##}] &
a_ ⊕ b_ := CirclePlus[a, b]
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Function in (SparseArray[Band[{1,1}]->{##1}]&)[a_,b_] is Protected. >>

I want to define the operator ⊕ to work like `+,-,*,/`, so it can be used as `a ⊕ b`.

Comment: `CirclePlus := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {##}] &;
Normal[a\[CirclePlus]b]`

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Can you explain why? and I want to define the operation `\[CirclePlus]` like `+,-,*,/` which can be used as `a \[CirclePlus] b`.

Comment: @EdenHarder Then you should define it as `CirclePlus[a_, b_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {a, b}]` and this can be used as `a ⊕ b`.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks! Can you analyze the error in my original code to teach me a lesson?

Comment: Certainly! But I'm afraid I'll have to write it in the morning... it's night time here and I'm sleepy. Sorry about that, but I'll come back to it.

Comment: Related: [Specifics of usage and internal work of *Set* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5846756/618728)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CirclePlus` is a built-in symbol already with no meaning for the *kernel*, but *meaning* in the front-end.

The second definition tried to use the first definition (with head 'Function'), which is protected. (Note the pattern `[a_,b_]` appearing in the error message, which tells you the left-hand-side is the issue.)

Just one line is enough as @rm-rf said, like this...

```
a_ ⊕ b_ := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1} -> {a, b}]]
```

The front-end translates `⊕` for you into `CirclePlus` - this is what I meant when said that it has *meaning* in the front-end.

*More detailed explanation*

I was thinking that what I said may not be clear enough, in the sense that the workings of `SetDelayed` (aka `:=`) were not clearly exposed.

The fact that `SetDelayed` has attribute `HoldAll` does not mean that the expression on the left is not evaluated by the *kernel* in order to determine which **head** the defining rule gets attached to. No, it is actually evaluated!

Let me illustrate with a simple and quick example. If you execute the following

```
MyX[1] := Y;
MyX[x_] := Z;
```

then which heads are being defined here?

```
MyX[1][a_] := a^2;
MyX[x][a_] := a;
```

Ask the *kernel*!

```
?Y
```

[image: Y defs]

```
?Z
```

[image: Z defs]

Interesting, ah?

So, this is what happened in your case. `CirclePlus` was undefined for the *kernel* until you gave it the first definition **without a pattern**. When you attempted the second one, the *kernel* already knew something about the head and try to evaluate it and got `Function`. There the evaluation stopped and then it tried to associate the second rule with this `Function` head - error.

By the way, be careful your definition only knows about `CirclePlus[a,b]`, but the front end treats `a ⊕ b ⊕ c` as a single `CirclePlus[a,b,c]`, which is unknown to the *kernel* with the definition provided.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer! But we should wait for @rm-rf waking up. He has promised to give an answer.

Comment: "When you attempted the second one, the kernel already knew something about the head and try to evaluate it and got Function", can we avoid this?

Comment: @EdenHarder caya has written a nice answer to your question and I have nothing more to add :)

Comment: In the original two-line definition, one can also just switch the order of the lines. The reason why this works is exactly what caya wrote.

Comment: Thanks @rm-rf, I couldn't resist explaining this aspect of the _Mathematica_ programming language :)