# ContourIntegral keyword

Tags: system

In version 10.1 ContourIntegral seems to be a keyword as it appears in the completion box. However, one cannot access to the documentation page by pressing "F1".

[image]

Does anyone know what is it for?

Comment: Somewhat related Q&A: [(17429)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17429), [(39987)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39987), [(74089)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74089)

Answer (score 5):

See [ContourIntegral](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ContourIntegral.html).

It's an undefined symbol, which the user may define.  It also has its own input form.

```
\[ContourIntegral] f \[DifferentialD]x // FullForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also the tutorial [Operators without Built-in Meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html).